# add contant to XML through JDOM

Tags: xml, jdom

I have been starting to look at JDOM. Until now I have created a file which has the name file.xml. Now I would like to add some content in the XML file, but I am a little bit insecure how to do that?
That could fx be:
    - name
    - lastname
    - age

Hope someone can help me? Best Regards from Julie

```
    ppackage examplePackage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

public class ReadXMLFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            write();
            read();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        public static void read() throws JDOMException, IOException {


            SAXBuilder reader = new SAXBuilder();
            Document document = reader.build(new File("file.xml"));
            XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
            xout.output(document, System.out);
        }

        public static void write() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {



Document document = new Document();
        Element root = new Element("document");
        root.setAttribute("file", "file.xml");
        root.addContent(new Element("style"));
        document.setRootElement(root);

        Element person = new Element("Person");             
        person.setAttribute("name", "Mads");
        }
}
```

Print out in console:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document file="file.xml">
  <style />
</document>
```

In this case it should print out the person with the name "Mads" right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `read` method you probably want to change this line:

> System.out.println(document.getContent());

to something like:

```
 XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
 xout.output(document, System.out);
```

That will print the entire document, not just the `toString()` on parts of it.

Then, about adding the content.... in the `write()` method:

- You set the root element with:

  > ```
  >     Document document = new Document();
  >     Element root = new Element("document");
  >     root.setAttribute("file", "file.xml");
  >     root.addContent(new Element("style"));
  >     document.setRootElement(root);
  > ```

  .There is nothing wrong with that, but it is often more commonly done like:

  ```
      Element root = new Element("document");
      root.setAttribute("file", "file.xml");
      root.addContent(new Element("style"));
      Document document = new Document(root); // note the root constructor
  ```
- if you want to add additional content, for example:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      Element count = new Element("count" + i);
      root.addContent(count);
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  Element person = new Element("person");        
  person.setAttribute("name", "Jon");
  person.setAttribute("lastname", "Skeet");
  person.setAttribute("age", "37");
  root.addContent(person);
  ```

**Update**: Finally, after you have added the content, you actually need to write the file out to disk:

```
XMLOutputter xmlout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.xml")) {
    xmlout.output(document, fos);
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your very good answer and time to give the answer. I have just changed the code(I have edited my question). When I run the code, it still print the old one out